# How to create a shell dictionary from an output of a python script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, python

My python scripy print a string by `print("declare -A gaps=( [2019-2-24]=4 )")` and I can run `declare -A gaps=( [2019-2-24]=4 )` on a bash shell to create a dictionary named `gaps`.

In my bash script, I use a variable named `gap_string` to access the output of python scripy. Then I use backquote surrounded the `gap_string` expected to create a dictionary which failed got and error: `declare: “[2019-2-24]=4”: is not a valid identifier`.

More details:

code in my bash script:

```
declare -A birthdays=(["${year}0120"]="GG")

gap_string=`/home/roach/.config/argos/LunarSolarConverter.py ${!birthdays[@]}`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    `$gap_string`
fi
```

code in my Python script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    converter = LunarSolarConverter()
    gaps_string = ["declare -A gaps=("]
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    today_date = today.date()
    year = today.year
    isleap = (year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0))
    days_this_year = 366 if isleap else 365
    for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
        year, month, day = int(sys.argv[i][:-4]), int(sys.argv[i][-4:-2]), int(sys.argv[i][-2:])
        lunar = Lunar(year, month, day, isleap)
        solar = converter.LunarToSolar(lunar)
        gap = (datetime.date(solar.solarYear, solar.solarMonth, solar.solarDay) - today_date).days % days_this_year
        if gap <= 4:
            gaps_string.append(f"[{solar.solarYear}-{solar.solarMonth}-{solar.solarDay}]={gap}")
    gaps_string.append(")")
    if len(gaps_string) == 2:
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print(" ".join(gaps_string))
        sys.exit(0)
```

What python script do is change Chinese lunardate to solardate, and then calculate the days between today and the specific solardate, and then to remind my family members' birthday to me.

Comment: I think you should add more info like how you assigned value into `gap_string`. And also the code *Then I use backquote surrounded the gap_string expected to create a dictionary*

Comment: @PRY Hi, thanks for your advice, I updated more details!

Comment: @PRY `declare -A gaps=( [2019-2-24]=4 )` got this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backticks is wrong: that will attempt to execute the string like an external command. But the string is a *bash* specific command, and has be be executed in the context of the current shell. There are 2 ways to do this:

1. use `eval` with a [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

   ```
   gaps=$( your_python_command )
   eval "$gaps"
   # or, the variable is unnecessary:
   eval "$( your_python_command )"
   ```
2. use `source` with a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

   ```
   source <( your_python_command )
   ```

In both cases, you better be sure you know what the python script is outputting: you don't want to execute any untrusted code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! First method worked. I alse tested `source < ( python /home/roach/.config/argos/LunarSolarConverter.py ${!birthdays[@]} )` got an error: `Unexpected symbol "(" has a syntax error nearby`.

Comment: No space between the `<` and the `(`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set -x` command for debugging. Take the below exmple:

```
set -x
declare -A gaps=( [2017-02-11]=4 )
```

Will give you:

```
+ gaps=([2017-02-11]=4)
+ declare -A gaps
```

And

```
s="declare -A gaps=( [2017-02-11]=4 )"
$s
```

Will give you:

```
+ declare -A 'gaps=(' '[2017-02-11]=4' ')'
```

So you can see that in the second case commands which are executing are:

```
declare -A 'gaps=('
declare -A [2017-02-11]=4
declare -A )
```